# Set custom Customer attribute value programmatically Magento 2

Tags: magento, import, magento2

I am importing some customers with :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $customerFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');


        $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->setWebsiteId(1)->loadByEmail('customrr@custom.com');


        try {
            if(!empty($customer->getData('email')))
            {
                $customer->setAttr1(1); // Attr1 = Name of the custom Attribute 
                $customer->setAttr2(2); // Attr2 = Name of the custom Attribute 
            }
            else
            {
                $customer = $customerFactory->create()->setWebsiteId(1);
            }


            $customer->setLastname("Lastname");

            $customer->setFirstname("Firsty");

            .....

            $customer->save();
```

The customer is saved with all his standard attributes correctly but my new attributes won't be saved anyway.  I've also tried :

```
$customer->setCustomAttribute('Attr1','value');
```

but this didn't work too.

The custom Attribute are shown correclty in Magentos 2 backoffice and the values are saved correctly too if creating a customer manually.

Comment: Share the code which you used to create customer attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
$customer-> setData('Attr1','value');
```

and don't forget to save and log the information:

```
try {
    $customer->save();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // log exception so you can debug the issue if there is one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface 
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        Config $eavConfig
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) 
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute', [
                'label' => 'Label',
                'system' => 0,
                'position' => 720,
                'sort_order' => 720,
                'visible' => true,
                'note' => '',
                'type' => 'int',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'backend' => \Custom\Module\Model\Customer\Attribute\Backend\DoWHatEver::class,
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $this->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute');
        $attribute->addData([
                'is_user_defined' => 1,
                'is_required' => 0,
                'default_value' => 0,
                'used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer']
            ])->save();
    }
    
    public function getEavConfig() 
    {
        return $this->eavConfig;
    }
}
```